# Using OAuth for Spring Rest API

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication

I am developing a application which uses Spring Rest services. I am using basic auth for authentication. I know that it is unsecure. My end client are capable of handling OAuth. I want to use OAuth, can any one point me to how to do OAuth in Java. I saw some examples they mention about Twitter , Google and Facebook.But I don't want to use social networking sites.

Comment: did you look at spring security? I think it can filter requests with spring-security-filter and also check OAuth credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OAuth is a concept, and not any library which you can inject, (of course libraries exists to implement that)

So if you want to have OAuth in your application (i.e your application has its own OAuth), you have to setup following things

- Authentication Server
- Provide Provision to Manage OAuth Clients
- Manage AccessTokens

Check out the OAuth 2.0 Specification to get clear understanding of how it works and how to build your own.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

Comment: I want to have OAuth in my application. If I do that will it become similar to basic auth? As I am passing credentials for generating token to my own application

Comment: the credentials will be entered by the user, and handed by single point (your application, your login page), and for further request you will be requesting using access token. 
OAuth is for mainly authorization, and much more than basic auth